# String concatenation leaving a " at the beginning

Tags: javascript, string, split, concatenation

I am creating a string called temp by concatenation

```
var temp = ""; //this is what we will send to the server

for(var i = 1; i < 25; i++){
    console.log("checking" + i);
    if($('[name = '+ i + "]").is(":checked")){

        console.log("in the if");
        temp = temp + hourArrayOpen[i - 1] + " - " + hourArrayClose[i - 1] + ",";
    }
}
```

On the client side this string prints out as this:

```
11:00am - 12:00pm,12:00pm - 1:00pm,
```

which is exactly what I want.

Now on the server side, I am using `split()` to parse this into an array.

```
//parse string to array
var hours = req.body.hours.split(",");

//remove last element because it's ""
hours.splice(hours.length-1, 1);

console.log(hours[0]);
```

Now, when I log this, I get the following `"11:00am - 12:00pm` (a quotation at the beginning but only for the first element in the array)

Why is this happening?

Comment: you can check the string that is being sent to the backend once. Browser might be adding some double quotes when it encodes the data. Go to browser console/network tab and see, the exact content being sent across the wire...

Comment: Seems you're putting quotes around the final string. The last quote isn't there because of the `.splice()`. Guessing that the data is getting `JSON.stringify()` on the client somewhere along the line.

Comment: thank u!!! can't believe i didnt realize

Comment: Why do you want a trailing comma, btw? Why not use a map `var list = $.map($('[name]').filter(':checked'), function(e) { var i = parseInt($(e).attr('name')); return hours[i].toString(); })` and then you can always do a `list.join(',')` or `list.join(', ')` etc when you just need to render it to text. (with an `hours` array containing objects that represent open/close intervals, not two separate arrays)